# How can i share an export setup from one computer/user to another in Trimble Pathfinder Office?

Tags: trimble, pathfinder

I have looked in the Pathfinder documentation and can't find anything on sharing an export setup.  See image [image: Existing Export Set]

Is there any way to take this set up file from my computer and share it with coworkers so we all have the exact same set up file?